# Window not showing up in Window menu

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am creating an OS X application with multiple windows.  The main window appears in the Window menu as expected.

I'm creating the 2nd NSWindow using initWithWindowNibName.  It appears as expected when I call showWindow.  However the window doesn't show up in the Window menu (under "Bring all to front" and the main window's name).

I tried:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] addWindowsItem:[winController window] 
                                                title:@"The Window" 
                                                filename:NO];    }
```

I also tried:

```
[[winController window] setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:NO];
```

Neither of these seemed to help.

If you can't tell, I'm new to OS X (but I know Obj-C relatively well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was creating the window in a NSResponder's init function.  Somehow it was happening too early and the sharedApplication wasn't ready yet.  When I moved the window creation into an awakeFromNib everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The Window Programming Guide says that "This menu automatically lists windows that have a title bar and are resizable and that can become the main window".  Is there a reason that this window cannot become main, e.g., is it an `NSPanel`?

Comment: I know, that is what is so confusing to me.  Its a Xib created by going to File > New > New File, and selecting "User Interface" and Window.  And then I have a subclass of NSWindowController that I create like this

  [[MyNSWindowController alloc]
                     initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowXIB"]